# Is there a way to hide the trackchange panel while continuing tracking changes in overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, trackchanges

I am using Overleaf as Latex editor. Specially, on online meetings continuously showing trackchanges panel becomes annoying. Is there a way to hide it while still continuing tracking changes.
Many thanks,
Ferda

Comment: I'm not sure this site is appropriate place for asking for support for commercial software, better to ask overleaf support, as you are using the paid-for version.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, please feel free to send these kinds of questions to Overleaf support: https://www.overleaf.com/contact. To answer your question though, It sounds like you want to hide the Review pane, which can be done by clicking on the Review button at the top the editor.  See here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Track_Changes_in_Overleaf.